# Access variable in C#(code-behind) from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind, bing-maps

Before I explain my situation, please have a look at the very important notice!!

1.My javascript is not embedded in .aspx file, so something like

```
    var strMessage = '<%= str%>';
    StartGeocoding(strMessage);
```

is not working (I tried a lot, but if you can improve it please let me know)

2.Also, I already used

```
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( , , , )
```

function, so I think I am not allowed to use twice.

================================================================

So, here 
In "Location.js" (seperated from .aspx)

```
    function LoadMap(count) {       
        var asdf = (something variable from code-behind);
        var counts = count;                      
        myMap = new VEMap("mapDiv");
        myMap.LoadMap();
        StartGeocoding(asdf);    // it will show the map with location info of "asdf"
    }
```

In code behind, there is something

```
    public string blahblah = "1 Yonge Street"
```

Basically, I will get the address from code behind, and I will show it using javascript.
If you (my LORD!) can teach me how to get the variable in C# from javascript, that would be very appreciated!!!

If you guys wanna challenge, here is bonus(?) question

actually, I will show the multiple location in a map. Therefore, instead of having one string "blahblah", I might have a list of string

```
    <list>Locationlist        //not array
```

So, 'count' in LoadMap() function will recognize how many entries I have. How to get each location information from javascript? is this possible? Any idea?

Comment: You can put construct a comma separated string from your List<string> and then register that under a js variable using RegisterStartupScript. You can call RegisterStartupScript multiple times, just give it a different key parameter

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What do you mean by "put cunstruct a comma separated string from List<string>"? In my list, there would be "1 Yonge Street", "100 Yonge Street", "123 Microsoft Way" etc. Therefore, count would be 3 for this example and I want to show the location by calling StartGeocoding(asdf) fucntion. LoadMap() fucntion is incompleted as I couldn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I had in mind. 
On code-behind, let's say the Page_Load method, you can have the following code:

```
List<string> locations = new List<string> { "1 Yonge Street", "100 Yonge Street", "123 Microsoft Way" };

//transform the list of locations into a javascript array. 
//The generated script should look like window.myLocations = ['1 Yonge Street', '100 Yonge Street', etc];
StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
script.Append("window.myLocations = [");
foreach(string location in locations){
  if(script.Length > 0){
    script.Append(", ");
  }
  script.Append("'"+System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(location) +"'");
}
script.Append("];");

//then register this script via RegisterStartupScript.
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript( this, this.GetType(), "registerMyLocations", script.ToString(), true);
```

At this point you can acccess the registered array in Location.js:

```
function LoadMap(/*count*/) {       
        var asdf = window.myLocations[0]; //this would be '1 Yonge Street' in your case
        alert(asdf);
        //var counts = count;
        var counts = window.myLocations.length;                      
        alert(counts);

        myMap = new VEMap("mapDiv");
        myMap.LoadMap();
        StartGeocoding(asdf);    // it will show the map with location info of "asdf"
    }
```

Some remarks:

- To use the StringBuilder class you need to add a "using System.Text" at the top of the file;
- the System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode is needed to ensure that the serverside strings are correctly encoded (taken from [Caveats Encoding a C# string to a Javascript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413421/caveats-encoding-a-c-sharp-string-to-a-javascript-string)). It is available only in .Net 4, from what I understand.
- if you have a ScriptManager on the page it is best to use the RegisterStartupScript on the ScriptManager rather then the method in the Page.ClientScript

I cannot test the above code right now but you should get the basic ideea.

Answer (score 1):

You have basically two options:

1.) output the data to the page from code-behind, let's say to hiddenfield, and then use javascript to retrieve these values (it's pretty straightforward)

2.) use ajax and get the values as needed

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, how can I assign the value to hiddenfield from code-behind? I have to idea to get the ID.. Let say, 
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hflocation" Value="" />

Comment: @KidongChrisKim, hflocation.Value = "whatever you want". If it's a more complex type, I'd suggest to serialize it to JSON first, which can be then easily parsed by javascript.

Comment: Thank you for quick comment! To be honest with you, I have no idea about ajax or JSON. To google that, would you please give me some keyword? (serialize?) Thank you so much!

Comment: @KidongChrisKim, sure, just google for "json C# serialize" and for ajax I like to use jQuery "$.ajax". Maybe you will need "jquery parse json". Try to find some examples and I'm sure you'll figure it out in no time, it's really easy :)